# JavaScript game with css generated blocks, character failing to jump onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, game-physics

I have the following game and the css green block is failing to jump on click. I can't seem to spot my error.

As you can see I have added the onclick event in the HTML and as far as I know the css animation is correctly coded in the style file. I want the character to jump calling the CSS animation, and ideally avoid a JScript function at this stage (or have **both alternatives** to see which is **simpler** for young students)

Can anyone spot and point out the error please.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 22;
}

#game {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 4px solid #f74cbc
}

#character {
  width: 30px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  top: 380px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  animation: jump 500ms;
}

#enemy {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 320px;
  left: 440px;
  animation: moveenemy 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    top: 380px;
  }
  30% {
    top: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 380px;
  }
}

@keyframes moveenemy {
  0% {
    top: 440px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 58px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 320px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" onclick="jump()">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Battle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>TG</h1>
  <p>Avoid the red</p>

  <div id="game">
    <div id="character"></div>
    <div id="enemy"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Update:

I know I could use a Jscript function like the below, but even that does not work?

**JavaScript tried below** (in the script.js)

```
function jump(){
    if(character.classlist!="animate"){
    character.classList.add("animate");
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        character.classList.remove("animate");
    },500);
    
}
```

Ideally, as mentioned, I want the simplest possible solution. Could both errors be pointed out (solution provided) so both alternatives are present in the answer. Which is the recommended way?

Comment: Can you show your script.js?

Comment: There is nothing there - so I doubt that is the problem

Comment: The js file is empty. This is just purely HTML and CSS

Comment: Well maybe this is the problem? `jump() is undefined`. If your JS file is empty, what do you expect to happen? :)

Comment: I thought the jump was referencing the CSS function - please advise.

Comment: script.js is empty? you have attached an callback function onClick [jump()], the browser can't find jump() variable/function

Comment: `onclick="jump()"` triggers a Javascript function, not a CSS function. CSS has no functions (as far as I know).

Comment: edited question. Is it not possible for the character to jump (referencing the animation) rather than Jscript

Comment: Not if you want the character to jump at some user-controlled time (like here, when the user clicks).  That requires javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could toggle a `CSS` class with javascript that executes your jump animation. You can't reference a `CSS` animation directly via `JS`

```js
// Get your character div
const character = document.getElementById('character');

// Create "jump" animation that you referenced in the "onclick".
function jump() {
  // Check if the animation is already started
  if(!character.classList.contains('jumping')){
    // Add the "jumping" class
    character.classList.add('jumping');
    // After "500 ms" remove the "jumping" class, duration must match your CSS animation length
    setTimeout(function() {
      character.classList.remove('jumping');
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 22;
}

#game {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 4px solid #f74cbc
}

#character {
  width: 30px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  top: 380px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* Moved the animation to it's own class so we can toggle it */
#character.jumping {
  animation: jump 500ms;
}

#enemy {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 320px;
  left: 440px;
  animation: moveenemy 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    top: 380px;
  }
  30% {
    top: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 380px;
  }
}

@keyframes moveenemy {
  0% {
    top: 440px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 58px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 320px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" onclick="jump()">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Battle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>TG</h1>
  <p>Avoid the red</p>

  <div id="game">
    <div id="character"></div>
    <div id="enemy"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks - could you comment what exactly you have added please

Comment: this is good -and clearly works but more complex. I am aiming this at very young students, so the simplest possible solution. I think the JavaScript in this case, given your answer, may be that. Are you able to include, in your answer, a correct to my JavaScript code to make it jump, so I can accept your answer please. This provides both alternatives

Comment: I've edited the snippet with some comments to explain what it does. I Hope this helps

Comment: thank you! Are you able to comment on which is better practice? Also, is there a reason my JavaScript is not working? Which, in your opinion, is simpler/more straightforward

Comment: Yes, i made a typo, should be fixed aleady. All did was change the code from [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to regular functions. It mostly comes down to what you prefer, though there are some (scope) differences. I try to keep my code as modern as possible to decrease side effects and most of the time it takes less code to do the same thing. If you 're worried about older browsers there are things like [compilers](https://babeljs.io/) but that's a whole new topic.